# How to change package name dynamically for android before build in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-android

We have an application that has same code but different apks for different countries.

As of now I am Changing id in **config.xml** then removing and adding android platform to generate a build.

I want to make such automated system like i can make multiple apks from the existing parent code with different package names and version codes.I want to make such a script that when i run it on command line i will be able to build a new apk from the parent code just by package name.

will be default package name.

1) **com.proj.stg.ApplicationName** 
2) **com.proj.ws.stg.ApplicationName**.

What approach should I use to change package name dynamically?

Comment: Use 2 projects and just copy your `src` folder files and make different APK's.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @KlemensZleptnig I have written hook to change bundle id before the build.